# Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 14742

Tags: android, flutter, dart, location, geolocator

[image]I'm using location: ^4.4.0 to fetch the location.
Below code to fetch the location. This is not working with Android 9.0 Google APIs, with Rest android it's working good.

```
Future<Location> getCurrentLocation() async {
    loc.Location currentLocation = loc.Location();
    loc.LocationData? _locationData;
    try {
      _locationData = await currentLocation.getLocation();
    } catch(e){
      print('getCurrentLocation Error: ${e.toString()}');
    }
    return Location(_locationData?.latitude ?? 0.0, _locationData?.longitude ?? 0.0);
  }
```

This is the error it's throwing on calling await currentLocation.getLocation(); this.

E/AndroidRuntime(10027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10027): Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 10027
E/AndroidRuntime(10027): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.settings.LocationSettingsCheckerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0808d3
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0808d3
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:887)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:802)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at bwml.run(:com.google.android.gms@214515028@21.45.15 (100400-411636772):9)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6282)
E/AndroidRuntime(10027):    at euv.platform_runOnUiThread(:com.google.android.gms@214515028@21.45.15

please help, Thanks in advance.